# What is the process for finding the type of a library's component in Typescript React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Usually I would just look it up on Stackoverflow/google but this doesn't work for everything.

As an example, suppose I want to make an array of react-bootstrap components. How would I find the type of that array?

```js
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";

...

const myArray : TypeOfListGroupThatIDontKnow[] = [];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with an open-source library, which is usually the case, I think the best way is to just look at the source code. In your example, you may find what you're looking for here: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/984e22702e811467a06dba084f18414adced47b4/src/ListGroup.tsx

Even better, a good IDE will let you easily navigate to the source you have in your `node_modules`. If not, you can dig around in that directory yourself. Typescript-based libraries should provide their type definitions.

Comment: Thanks! How would I then go about using this type? When I import it, I don't see the type inside of the ListGroup.d.ts file where the component seems to be imported from.

Comment: @Danny - created a CRA app with the typescript template and installed the latest version of react-bootstrap.  I added the following line, and it seems to work fine: 

 const listGroups: ListGroup[] = []

The ListGroup.d.ts file does declare and export a type for ListGroup.